# Finding the limit of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

[image]

Using the given condition to find$$
\lim_{x \to 2} f(x).$$

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-(x+2)}{x-2}=\frac{5}{6}$ and $\lim_{x\to 2}(x-2)=0$. Then $\lim_{x\to 2}(f(x)-(x+2))=\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-(x+2)}{x-2}=0\frac{5}{6}=0$. Since $\lim_{x\to2}(x+2)=4$, then $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=\lim(f(x)-(x+2))+\lim_{x\to2}(x+2)=0+4=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since

$$f(x)=f(2)+f'(2)(x-2)+o(x-2)$$

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)-(x+2)}{x-2}=\frac{5}{6}\implies\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(2)+f'(2)(x-2)-(x+2)+o(x-2)}{x-2}=\frac56$$

the limit exists if and only if

$$\lim_{x\to2} f(2)-(x+2)=0\implies f(2)=4$$

and since $f(x)$ is continuos

$$\lim_{x\to2} f(x)=f(2)=4$$